# BroadcastReceiver does not get data from notification button

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, notification-action

I am trying to make notification with remove button, notifications are stored in SQLite DB and after the press, I want to remove "record" by id. Firstly I get a notification, store it to db , store unique id and pass it to a method which creates a notification. It gets fine in the method.

```
    public static String CUSTOM_ACTION = "com.example.app.Services.REMOVE";
    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    snoozeIntent.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);
    snoozeIntent.putExtra("NOT_WORKING", String.valueOf(id));
    PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_bell)
            .setContentTitle("Loggly")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete_forever_black_24dp, "Remove", snoozePendingIntent);
```

then I have a broadcast receiver for handling data from notification. Here is how it looks in my manifest file.

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.app.Services.REMOVE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And here is the broadcast receiver the value which I got from extras is always null ... I have been trying to find a solution, but with no result.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String id;

        if (extras != null) {
            id = extras.getString("NOT_WORKING");
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.cancel(0);
            }

            Intent inten = new Intent(context, RemoveService.class);
            inten.putExtra("NOT_WORKING", id);
            context.startService(inten);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I am starting intent service, which should delete the "record" from the database, but when the broadcast receiver does not receive id it can't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created a sample notification on my side and the problem is the way you are creating the pendingIntent. Just add the proper flag to the pendingIntent parameter and it will work fine.

```
PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You can use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` as well. If it satisfies your use case. You can go through different flags which can be used in [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)